# Intel P6100 CPU and Mobile Intel® HM55 Express Chipset

Tags: memory, ddr3, chipset

I have an Asus K52F-BBR5 notebook that uses an Intel P6100 ( 2GHZ 15x multiplier) and HM55 Express Chipset.  I'm looking to replace it's 3GB with 8GB.

The Crucial database seems to indicate that a PC3-8500 CAS 7 and PC3-10666 CAS 9 will both work.  I'm not up to date on the latest DDR3 nomencalature and I'm wondering which would provide better performance.  The price difference is negligible.

Drawing on past experiences from many many years ago I could make an argument for either based on sync/async bus speed arguments and CAS latency differences but the truth is I don't know enough about the HM55 chipset to know which would be the correct choice.

Does anyone know the answer or point me to information that would help me make the choice? I'm pretty sure the performance difference will be somewhat negligible also but still I'd like to make the optimal choice.

Comment: I read somewhere that this chipset will always take 10666 memory and run it at 8500 speeds when you have a dual core cpu but I have do evidence that the person who wrote that is correct.  Assuming they are correct, they said the SPD timings would adjust to the lower timings and the result would be the same performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/datasheet/322169.pdf has everything you need to know and more, and with a little google search im sure it could and would answer your questions to a tee.

Comment: but its like 1000+ pages soooo, im not summarizing for you. ha ha.

Comment: Actually that's not useful at all.  It seems that the HM55 is just the platform controller hub and doesn't have anything to do with the memory interface.  That's a function of the CPU according to a block diagram that I found.  Time for me to rethink my question.

Comment: hmmm, that's disappointing. i always wanted to present a document that was 1000 pages long that was actually useful.

Comment: I can live with that. ha ha. If you want a real answer, ill bump this for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I did it!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHrsgo20EbE

Main reason to make this video:
I answered on question about possibility to install Core i7 processor and 16Gb of RAM on old chipset Intel HM55 Express

Before Upgrade this laptop have such specs:
Chipset: Intel HM55 Express
Processor: Intel Core i3 370M 2.4 GHz Cache 3 MB 
HDD 500Gb
Video: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6550M 1GB DDR3

After Upgrade:
Core i7 720QM
16 GB of RAM (from Apple)
IPS screen 1366x768
1 TB HDD

Comment: Can you summarise the video contents here in case the video ever gets removed? As a quick aside, please don't post in any language other than English.